# Write Ruby code inside TinyMCE textbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tinymce, erb

Is it possible to write Ruby code inside the TinyMCE textbox? I've tried accessing some model data by putting <%= foo.bar %> inside a TinyMCE textbox but when rendering the raw text it displays the Ruby code as is - it doesn't render the Ruby code, just treats it as part of the text.

I've tried the `raw` and `html_safe` methods but neither worked.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I'm using the `tinymce-rails` gem and the following is the code in my form:

```
  <td><%= section_form.text_area :html, class: "tinymce", style: "width:800px; height:300px;" %></td>
  <%= tinymce content_css: asset_path('tiny_mce_content.css') %>
```

Comment: How are you trying to add your text to tinymce? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488189/how-to-set-the-initial-text-an-a-tinymce-textarea may be relevant. Are you using tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent?

Comment: I'm using the `tinymce-rails` gem. I updated the question with code from my form.

Answer (score 1):

Just run it through ERB, e.g:

```
ERB.new("<%= 'something'.upcase %>").result
=> "SOMETHING"
```

If you're looking to pass variables in, check out this post, which has a few options: [Ruby templates: How to pass variables into inlined ERB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338960/ruby-templates-how-to-pass-variables-into-inlined-erb)

Comment: Unfortunately the code above doesn't display the Ruby code any different. It's still not returning the object - just the text. I tried `<% foo = ERB.new("<%= current_profile.name %>").result %>` then displaying foo; I also tried `<% foo = ERB.new("<%= current_profile.name %>").result(namespace.instance_eval { binding }) %>` and then displaying foo but both ways give me a syntax error: `syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('`.

Comment: @mmichael Yes, unfortunately this doesn't get you access to the current variable scope. You have to jump through some hoops-- take a look at the post I linked to in the answer.

Comment: I'll take a closer look. Thank you for your response. I'll give it another go tomorrow.