# How to add custom text when JCE 2.3.1 is loaded?

Tags: joomla, default-value, joomla-article, joomla-content-editor

I have a Joomla 2.5 site with K2 and I have installed JCE Editor 2.3.

How can I add custom text by default so that when I open a new article in my editor, some text is preloaded?

The custom text is my ads3ns3 script and some other divs. If I can get this to automatically appear, then I can bypass the tedious copy/paste step every time.

I searched all the JSE files, but I didn't find any input field that would hold my custom text.

I've open all the .php files but still nothing.

Comment: Is this what your require? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488189/how-to-set-the-initial-text-an-a-tinymce-textarea

Comment: @Lodder something like this... but i am looking for the correct file to open it, and edit it so the editor loads the html or text that i want. Thank you for your fast reply Sir!

Comment: `plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php`

Comment: If you ever have questions specifically for "joomla peeps", please ask your question at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange. @Ire

Answer (score 0):

You could use **JCE Template Manager** plugin to achieve this without need to rewrite JCE core files .. JCE is known as a target for Joomla hacks and needs to be updated regularly, and if you edit JCE core files you would have to apply described change all over again with every new update.